Step in Theorem 2.12 (Every well-ordered set is isomorphic to a unique ordinal number) from Jech's Set Theory
The following is from Jech's Set Theory:

Theorem 2.12. Every well-ordered set is isomorphic to a unique ordinal
number.
Proof. The uniqueness follows from Lemma 2.7. Given a well-ordered set $W$,
we find an isomorphic ordinal as follows: Define $F(x) = \alpha$ if $\alpha$ is isomorphic
to the initial segment of $W$ given by $x$. If such an $\alpha$ exists, then it is unique.
By the Replacement Axioms, $ F(W) $ is a set. For each $x \in W$, such an $\alpha$ exists (otherwise consider the least $x$ for which such an $\alpha$ does not exist). If $\gamma$ is the least $\gamma \not\in F(W)$ then $F(W) =\gamma$ and we have an isomorphism of $W$ onto $\gamma$.

I'm trying to show that "for each $x\in W$, such an $\alpha$ exists": let $x$ be the least element of $W$ such that $W_{<x}$ is not order isomorphic to any ordinal.

Case 1: $x$ is the minimal element of $W$. Then $W_{<x} \cong \emptyset$.
Case 2: $x = s(y)$ for some $y\in W$. Then $W_{<y}\cong \alpha$ for some ordinal $\alpha$, and thus $W_{<x}\cong \alpha + 1$.
Case 3: $x\ne s(y)$ for any $y\in W$. Let $O$ be the set of all ordinals order-isomorphic to some $y\in W$. I want to show
$$W_{<x}\cong \bigcup_{\beta\in O}\beta$$
and here I struggle to come up with anything worthwhile...


In case $3$, by definition of $\ x\ ,$ $\ F\big(W_{<x}\big)\ $ is a well-ordered set of ordinals. Let $\ \beta\ $ be the smallest ordinal such that $\ \beta\not\in F\big(W_{<x}\big)\ .$ If  $\ \gamma<\beta\ $ then $\ \gamma\in F\big(W_{<x}\big)\ $ (by definition of $\ \beta\ $). Conversely, if $\ \gamma\in F\big(W_{<x}\big)\ $ then $\ \gamma<\beta\ $ (because every ordinal less than $\ \gamma\ $ is in $\ F\big(W_{<x}\big)\   ,$ whereas $\ \beta\ $ isn't). Therefore $\ \beta=F\big(W_{<x}\big)\ $ and is isomorphic to $\  W_{<x}\ ,$ contradicting the assumption that no such ordinal exists.
